# Run Java single-file-source code with dependency and external library

Tags: java, jar, compilation, dependencies, java-runtime-compiler

I would like to know how to use the command line to run the Java single-file-source code.

I know that I cannot refer to outside classes per rules.

But I saw an YouTube video. The author is able to use external JAR library when he runs single-file-source code.

See this YouTube video @ 6:00 minute
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7Rp9hq0_Zk

He types:

java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar Database.java

I don't know how the database really works. I'm not there yet.

But if you guys can show me a quick example, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: `java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar Database.java` is already an example. The point is that you can set the class path to a place where all your dependencies are (in their case, mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar). Basically, I'm really not sure what you don't understand. That video is a great example of how to use external libraries when running single source files.

Comment: That's an incorrect example. Java is run against classes not source files. Also why would the entry point be in the same (only) classpath as the driver? It would not. Please describe what you want to do.

Comment: @g00se modern versions of java can do this

Comment: Ah right - i'll give it a go. I have a jdk 16. Nonetheless my second point holds
Tried it - wild! Not a class file in sight